# Unity can't access a random number from outside a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, int

I wanted to make a number guessing game where the computer guess your number and also you can guess it's number, but in the very finish, where i made a random number generator i stopped by a problem.

I made my function named `onGuessEnter` which is called when the player hits enter after he entered his guess, and my problem is that if i run the game (Visual Studio doesnt make a problem about it) Unity stops because of an error that contains the following line:

> RandomRangeInt can only be called from the main thread.

(If i put the random generator into the function, it generates a new random number every enter hit)

Can someone help me to make the input field and the random generator working well together? (I mean it has to generate a random number only once and not always when the enter button is getting pressed and i could access that random number from onGuessEnter)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class GuessManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public InputField input;
public Text text;
int random = Random.Range(0, 1000);

public void onGuessEnter() {

    print(random);
    int inum = int.Parse(input.text);

    if (inum == random) 
        text.text = "Congrats, you guessed it!";
    else if (inum < random)
        text.text = "Bigger!";
    else if (inum > random) 
        text.text = "Smaller!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use a simple trick like this (see below). We can't initialize `random` using the random number generator, but we can set it to a dummy value like -1, and then in our function we can check to see if it's -1, and if so, generate a random number. This will only happen once, since the random number can't be lower than 0.

```
int random = -1;

public void onGuessEnter() {
    if(random == -1){
        random = Random.Range(0, 1000);
    }
    print(random);
    int inum = int.Parse(input.text);

    if (inum == random) 
        text.text = "Congrats, you guessed it!";
    else if (inum < random)
        text.text = "Bigger!";
    else if (inum > random) 
        text.text = "Smaller!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

first, you should generate the Random number in `Awake` this way the random number will be created only once, and then just refer to it in your `onGuessEnter` method.
here in this example, I see if the user pressed the `Return` key then I will call your method to see if the guess is right.
at the end  attach the whole script to a `gameObject` and then in the editor drag your `InputField` and `Text` object to the empty slots which are provided under  `GuessManagerScript`.

```
public class GuessManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {
int random; 
   void Awake(){
       random= Random.Range(0, 1000);
      }
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
            {
                onGuessEnter();  
             }
     }

public void onGuessEnter() {
    int inum = int.Parse(input.text);

    if (inum == random) 
        text.text = "Congrats, you guessed it!";
    else if (inum < random)
        text.text = "Bigger!";
    else if (inum > random) 
        text.text = "Smaller!";
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: @Kristóf What's in this answer is what you should actually be doing which is using `Random.Range` in the `Awake` function to initialize the `random` variable. You don't need a dispatcher or any other API [Pic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418542/3785314) used in his answer